Error when trying to Send SMS via WP_REMOTE POST
i'm facing a little problem here. I have these codes saved in send-sms.php file trying to setup an SMS API using wp_remote_post with my site. As part of my trial every time i run my codes below i get response that i don't understand.
These are the codes
<?php

require_once 'wp-load.php';


$url = 'https://api.sprintsmsservice.com/api/SendSMS';

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
'method'      => 'POST',
'timeout'     => 45,
'redirection' => 5,
'httpversion' => '1.0',
'blocking'    => true,
'headers'     => array(),
'body'        => array(
'api_id'=>'xxxxxx',
'api_password'=>'xxxxxx',
'sms_type'=>'T',
'encoding'=>'T',
'sender_id'=>'ChonryOTP',
'phonenumber'=>255714812XXX,
'templateid'=>null,
'textmessage'=>'Hello, This is a test message',

),
'cookies'     => array()
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
$error_message = $response->get_error_message();
echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
echo 'Response:<pre>';
print_r( $response );
echo '</pre>';
}


?>

And these are the results when i run the send-sms.php file (You can view full results in this LINK)
                    [status_code] => 415
                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                    [success] => 
                    [redirects] => 0
                    [url] => https://api.sprintsmsservice.com/api/SendSMS/
                    [history] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [cookies] => WpOrg\Requests\Cookie\Jar Object
                        (
                            [cookies:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [filename:protected] => 
        )

)

Where i'm doing wrong? Because if i reload this file no SMS is sent to my number

Have you checked what format the API expects you to send data to it? 415 error means it didn't support the content type you sent it

I have twisted it a little bit, and now it is working.

I have fixed the problem, for future reference you might go through the codes below
$api_url = 'https://xxxxxxxx/api/SendSMS/'; // Replace with your API URL


$body = json_encode([
    
    'api_id'=>'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
    'api_password'=>'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
    'sms_type'=>'T', 
    'encoding'=>'T', 
    'sender_id'=>'xxxxx', 
    'phonenumber'=>'xxxxxx', 
    'templateid'=>null, 
    'textmessage'=>'Robson, This is test message' 
    
    
    
    //'api_key' => $api_key,
]);

$response = wp_remote_post($api_url, [
    'method'    => 'POST',
    'body'      => $body,
    'headers'   => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);

// Check for errors
if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    error_log('SMS API Error: ' . $response->get_error_message());
    return false;
}

// Handle the response
$response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
$decoded_response = json_decode($response_body, true);

if (isset($decoded_response['success']) && $decoded_response['success'] === true) {
    return true; // SMS sent successfully
}

error_log('SMS API failed with response: ' . $response_body);
return false;

